# Fast forward the timelapse vedio clip

Tags: imovie, time-lapse, ios

I created a timelapse video from iMovie software and set the time to 0.1 second for every image. But the final output is not satisfying. It seems a bit slow video. I need the clouds to move faster, but they are moving slowly. It is total of 30 second video. I need it to be 15 second video, so that I can get a desired effect. But I cannot change the setting lower then 0.1 second in iMovie. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have used the below link as reference: youtube.com/watch?v=dPlEAFyGznE

Comment: Can you remove every alternate image?

Comment: @Mulvya: I need that clip to be HD, with more fps.

Comment: How does removing images change frame size (HD)? What's the fps of your current output?

Comment: @Mulvya: I think it's 720fps right now. Though I'm not sure of it. I tried this for the first time. and above I've posted the youtube link from where I've done it.

Comment: It won't be 720fps. The resolution will be 720p i.e. 720 pixels tall, and usually 1280 pixels wide. That tutorial uses a project of 30 fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iMovie you can change the speed of a clip by selecting it in the timeline and then clicking on the icon that looks like a speedometer:

[image]

Then click on the "Speed:" popup menu and choose "Fast" or "Custom". The "Custom" setting lets you choose how much faster to make it (like 200%, or 50%).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. But to me it gives maximum to double the speed. So I tried to do that process 3 times. Now, I have a 9 second video clip (that's amazing, and exactly what I thought of). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/), a command line program, to double the video speed:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=0.5*PTS output.mp4
```